VSCODE: how to open file in current window while DISPLAY is set to display of ssh server
I am ssh'ed to a server. I use a software that is triggered through the CLI and has a GUI. So I did setenv DISPLAY <$DISPLAY value of the server>. Now this software works fine.
But I also have files that I edit on vscode. So when I run code <filename>. I would expect that it will open on the VSCODE window on the client. Instead, it opens on the server.
How do I get it to open the files on the client and the GUI on the server?

You shouldn't be running code on the remote server, but locally, and use it's built-in tooling to develop on the server via ssh.
